# Big } outside math mode

Tags: formatting

How to make something like this outside math mode?

A sample goes here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$$\left.\begin{aligned}
\text{inclusive} \\
\text{opposite} \\
\text{causal} \\
\text{parallel}
\end{aligned}\right\} \text{relationship}$$

\end{document}
```

I only know how to do this using `\left.` and `\right\}` in the math environment. Is there any ways outside math mode?

Comment: Can you show a complete use case? Is it because you're using `\text` everywhere that you want it "outside math mode"?

Comment: @Werner Yes, I can only make this with \left. ... \right\{ in math mode and I'm wondering is there something like this outside math mode.

Comment: ...yet the answer you accepted uses math mode. Hmmm... what am I missing here.

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257973) are solutions without math mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain it in text mode in at least two ways: either with `bigdelim` of with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{r@{\,}c} %
     inclusive & \rdelim\}{4}{*}[relationship] \\
     opposite \\
     causal \\
     parallel
   \end{tabular}
    \vskip 1em

  \begin{blockarray}{r\Right{\}}{relationship}} %
     inclusive \\
     opposite \\
     causal \\
     parallel
   \end{blockarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think that you need to use math-mode to some extent, however, you can reduce the number of `\text{...}` statements that you need if you use the `rcases*` environment from the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package:

```
\[
  \begin{rcases*}
    & inclusive\\
    & opposite\\
    & casual \\
    & parallel\\
  \end{rcases*}\text{relationship}
\]
```

This produces:

[image]

If you want to *pretend* that you are not using math-mode then you could wrap this into a command. The easiest way to do this is to define a command, say `\MyCases`, that takes a comma separated list of the cases that appear to the left of the brace together with the text that appears on the right. With this in place, you would be able to produce the output above using

```
\MyCases{inclusive, opposite, casual, parallel}{relationship}
```

The output is essentially the same as before. Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,etoolbox}

% \MyCases{comma separated list of cases}{right hand text}
\newcommand\MyCases[2]{%
   \[
     \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{&##1\\}% a line in the rcases* environment
     \begin{rcases*}
       \docsvlist{#1}% add the cases
      \end{rcases*}\text{#2}
   \]
}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{rcases*}
    & inclusive\\
    & opposite\\
    & casual \\
    & parallel\\
  \end{rcases*}\text{relationship}
\]

\MyCases{inclusive, opposite, casual, parallel}{relationship}

\end{document}
```

A few remarks about how the `\MyCases` command works. The key point is to use the `\docsvlist` command from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to loop over the contents of the comma separated list. This is done by redefining the `\do` command. After this, we are essentially just doing what I did above using the `rcases*` environment.